# AlertController - conflict with UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I'm working on an iOS project using Swift. I have simple login/register/lost password view controllers for security using Firebase. The issue is with the Reset Password View Controller. If a user clicks on it, they are sent (presented modally) to lost password view controller.

The problem with the current code is that when Firebase finds the entered email and sends a password reset email, I present Alert controller for confirmation for the user. The issue is that when I click "ok" on the Alert Controller, I want the Reset Password View Controller to be dismissed as well. Not sure why it's not working now. I do get emails, but when I click the OK button on the Alert controller, it only dismisses the Alert controller and the `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` doesn't seem to dismiss the modally presented Reset Password View Controller.

I tried with `self.dismissViewController(true, completion: nil)` as well as `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToLoginVC", sender: nil)`. Non seems to work and I can't figure why.

Here's the function itself:

```
    @IBAction func resetPasswordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = emailTextField.text

    if email != "" {

         DataService.ds.REF_BASE.resetPasswordForUser(email, withCompletionBlock: { error in

            if error != nil {

                // Error - Unidentified Email
                showAlert(title: "Unidentified Email Address", msg: "Please, re-enter the email you have registered with.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)

            } else {

                // Success - Sent recovery email

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Sent", message: "An email has been sent. Please, check your email now.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            }

         })

    } else {

        showAlert(title: "Error!", msg: "Email is required in order to reset your password. Please, enter your email. ", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered and provided the solution but removed his answer after it. So, this is what he said and it worked well (so credit goes to that person!):

```
    @IBAction func resetPasswordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    let email = emailTextField.text

    if email != "" {

         DataService.ds.REF_BASE.resetPasswordForUser(email, withCompletionBlock: { error in

            if error != nil {

                // Error - Unidentified Email
                showAlert(title: "Unidentified Email Address", msg: "Please, re-enter the email you have registered with.", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)

            } else {

                // Success - Sent recovery email

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Email Sent", message: "An email has been sent. Please, check your email now.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { action in

                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

                }))
                self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

         })

    } else {

        showAlert(title: "Error!", msg: "Email is required in order to reset your password. Please, enter your email. ", actionButton: "OK", viewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you don't need that.. :)

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle. Default, handler: { action in

   //Add your logic here

}))
```